# debugger for emacs to step through java source code

Tags: debugging, emacs

```
GNU Emacs 25.1.1
Fedora release 24 (Twenty Four)
Gradle 2.14.1
```

I have been doing a lot of java applications lately and want to know what is the best debugger for stepping through java applications.

I would like to debug my apps from inside emacs environment by setting breakpoints and inspecting variables, etc.

I am using gradle as my build tool for compiling the application.

I have no idea how to set this up, if someone could explain how to do this.

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: “What is the best FOO” is usually a request for an *opinion*; and opinion-asking questions are not a good fit for StackOverflow. Can you please [re-write the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that it asks a question with exactly one objectively correct answer.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `jdb` (it comes with [GUD](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Starting-GUD.html#Starting-GUD) and you should have nothing to install).

Just enter `M-x jdb ENT`

and enter the command you would like to launch jdb with (For example `jdb HelloWorld`) and run/debug like in a regular `jdb` session.

Comment: I'm having a hell of a time trying to install this on XEmacs 2.1

Answer (score 6):

I'm using [JDEE](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/) (Java Development Environment for Emacs) to develop Java in Emacs, you might want to try with it. It is an add on sotware package for Emacs that assists in the development of software in the Java Programming Language, and provides many Emacs commands that help with programming of Java, including [debugging](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/jdedoc/html/jde-ug/jde-ug-content.html#DebuggingApps).

> The JDE provides two options for debugging Java applications.
>
> - An Emacs interface to `jdb`, the command-line debugger that comes with the JDK. See [Debugging with jdb](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/jdedoc/html/jdb-ug/jdb-ug-frame.html) for more information.
> - JDEbug, a Java debugger developed specifically for use with the JDE. See [JDEbug User's Guide](http://jdee.sourceforge.net/jdedoc/html/jdebug-ug/jdebug-ug.html) for more information.
>
> JDEbug provides more debugging features.

Screenshots of JDEbug

[image]

[image]